# How to convert JSON into [WeatherModel] in Swift/SwiftyJSON?

Tags: json, swift, swift4

I was trying to make a weather app. And having a problem using SwiftyJSON.
I need to assign `[WeatherModel]` to my JSON data. 
Basically, I need to set json variable to weatherData. The code is below.

Here is my controller:

```
var weatherData = [WeatherModel]()

func getJSONData(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "weather", ofType: "json") {
            do{
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath), options: .alwaysMapped)
                let json = JSON(data: data)
                // And here I need to set json to weatherData

            } catch let error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completed()
            }
    } else {
        print("file not found")
    }
}
```

Here is my WeatherModel struct:

```
struct WeatherModel {
  let cod: String
  let message: Double
  let cnt: Int
  let list: [List]
  let city: City
}
```

Note: I really need this to be made using only SwiftJSON. Any help will be appreciated :]

Comment: Why bother with a 3rd party library? Just use the built in `Decodable` and `JSONDecoder`.

Comment: @rmaddy, because it's trivial to implement and (IMHO) `JSONDecoder` is a mess compared to SwiftyJSON.

Comment: If you are loading the data from the bundle the weather will never change . @LinusGeffarth Please reconsider your opinion. If you have no idea what you are doing SwiftyJSON might be a good choice. Otherwise `Codable` is much more powerful.

Comment: @vadian, that's what I'm saying. Codable is really neat. But for an easy start, SwiftyJSON is definitely a good way to jump right in.

Comment: You leave a lot of loose ends. Please provide an example of the JSON you expect to receive. Please provide your `List` struct in order to complete your `Model` expectations. Please provide _some_ idea on what you want to do in your `completed` closure and how you want to access your `weatherData` if it is not passed to your handler. There seem to be a lot more problems to your code than simply converting some (unknown) JSON to your `[WeatherModel]`.

Comment: @vadian I just need to complete my task. I have to convert it, and display it on my tableView, if you remember, you solved my previous problem. Please take a look, and say how can I do it using SwiftyJSON. Btw, thanks a lot!

Comment: @rmaddy Because my task description says that it should be using SwiftyJSON. Please take a look :)

Comment: In your previous question you are already using `Codable`. Why do you want to step backwards? `Codable` is much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we don't know what your JSON looks like.
To provide a sample, if this is what your JSON looked like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "cod": "some string here",
      "message": 2.0,
      "cnt": 1
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

... you would decode it as follows:

```
for (_, dict) in json["data"] {
    guard let cod = dict["cod"].string else { continue }
    guard let message = dict["message"].double else { continue }
    guard let cnt = dict["cnt"].int else { continue }
    // ...
    let weather = WeatherModel(cod: cod, message: message, cnt: cnt, ...)
    weatherData.append(weather)
}
```

You would have to modify this to work with your json format and the exact requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it later and let you know if something happens

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i am not sure about your json structure correctly.

```
struct WeatherModel:Codable {

    let cod: String
    let message: Double
    let cnt: Int
    let list: [List]
    let city: City

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
    {
       case title = "name"
       case url = "message"
       case cnt
       case list
      case city
    }

}

struct City:Codable {

    let name
}
struct List:Codable {

    //define your list data as in json
}
```

after this decode your json data.

```
if let wheatherData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherModel.self, from: data) {
 // here Is your json model weatherData
}
```

Comment: Yeah, basically I was parsing JSON using `Codable`. But now, it should be only using SwiftyJSON.